# Playfair Cipher Confusion with one column encryption

Tags: encryption, playfair

Recently I decided to learn "Playfair Cipher", and I have hit a road block.
what do i substitute the letters for if they are on the same column? Here is an example:

```
CIADX
BEFGH
KLMNO
PQRST
UVWYZ
```

With the Key being **CIAD**  (Random Text)

I want to spell the word "trust" but I do not know what rule to follow for the T & R. I would really appreciate help on this. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TR would be replaced using rule 2 of the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher#Description):

> If the letters appear on the same row of your table, replace them with the letters to their immediate right respectively (wrapping around to the left side of the row if a letter in the original pair was on the right side of the row).

So `TR` would become `PS`. See also step 10 of [the example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher#Example) there.

Note that `T` and `R` are on the same row, not the same column.

You may want to use a larger key (i.e. one that includes more characters of the alphabet).

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes! that solved my problem perfectly.